# websocket channel for the "current user"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, websocket, websocket-rails

Using [websocket-rails](https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails), I can use the
following code in my controller to tricker a websocket publish event:

```
WebsocketRails[:channel_name].trigger('event_name', { foo: "bar" }.to_json)
```

My goal is to create a pub-sub channel for the current user only. Take for example
the event "new chat message sent". I want to push this event only the receiver's channel.

I'm currently making a unique channel name for each user based on their ID. 
I put the following code in my controller (having defined a current_user 
method elsewhere:

```
WebsocketRails[:"user#{current_user.id}"].trigger("event_name", { foo: "bar" }.to_json)
```

And then in my Javascript, I subscribe the current user to their own channel with the following:

```
<% if @current_user %>
  var dispatcher = new WebSocketRails('localhost:3000/websocket');
  channel = dispatcher.subscribe('user<%= @current_user.id %>'); 
  channel.bind('event_name', function(data) {
    console.log(data)
  });
<% end %>
```

The gist of it is using string interpolation to make a new channel for each user, i.e.
`user12` and `user123` channels.

The problem is this is not really secure. Any user can access anyone else's
private channel just by pasting some Javascript in. For example, if user #1 wants
to access user #2's news feed, they could just type `dispatcher.subscribe('user2')`.

How would you solve this issue? Is there another pub-sub library which has this feature
built into it?

Looking on WebsocketRails' [wiki entry](https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails/wiki/Using-Private-Channels) on the subject,
I tried adding the follolwing code to config/initializers/websockets.rb

```
WebsocketRails::EventMap.describe do
  namespace :websocket_rails do
    subscribe :subscribe_private, to: ConnectionsController, with_method: :authorize_channels
  end
end
```

And the following to app/controllers/connections_controller.rb

```
class ConnectionsController < WebsocketRails::BaseController
  def authorize_channels
    channel_name = WebsocketRails[message[:channel]]
    current_user = User.find_by(id: session["current_user_id"])
    if current_user && "user#{current_user.id}".eql?(channel_name)
      accept_channel current_user
    else
      deny_channel({ message: "auth failed" })
    end
  end
end
```

And then elsewhere, I'm calling `WebsocketRails[:"user#{@current_user.id}"].make_private`

This doesn't seem to have any effect though.